# I want to only draw objects that a camera can see

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using THREEJS to build a dynamically generated 'minecraft' world based on a perlin noise generator.

Here's how far I am now: [Block World](http://www.sidequestsapps.com/sandbox_files/blocks/newgrid.html)

All is well so far except that, I'm noticing extreme performance (framerate) issues once I hit about 7,000 or so 'objects'.
My board usually generates around 12-14 thousand objects when I set the dimensions to be maximally 64*64*6 (the Perlin map obviously only uses a portion of the max blocks).

I "think" that what I want is to only draw the blocks that the camera can see. I think that I would set mesh.visible = false for the blocks that are behind the other blocks (hidden from the camera). Every frame I would just check to see what blocks are visible to the camera and set their mesh.visible = true.

Regardless, I think what I'm trying to accomplish is called "Occlusion Culling" but I cannot find any working examples of how to do this in ThreeJS.

One idea I had was to Raytrace for every pixel on the screen and look for intersections with the first object:

```
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```

I figure that even if I figured this out, it would probably be really slow anyways.

Another idea I had was to merge all of the meshes together into one. That was great. I got incredible frame rates from this. Unfortunately I lost the ability to individually manipulate the specific blocks, and their unique textures were also lost. I'd need a way to be able to still reference, change materials for and remove blocks within that merged geometry.
I don't think this is the solution.

Honestly I'm hoping someone here could explain how I can hide all of the meshes that are not visible because they are completely behind other objects.

Thanks

EDIT: Concerning the suggesting to implement frustrum culling, I tried this already

```
            var counter = 0;
            //
            // Only draw objects that you can see... I think
            frustum.setFromMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse));
            for (var i=0; i<world.length; i++) {
                for (var j=0; j<world[i].length; j++) {
                    for (var d=0; d<world[i][j].length; d++) {
                        if ( world[i][j][d].type !== -1 ) {
                            if ( frustum.intersectsObject( world[i][j][d].block ) ) {
                                world[i][j][d].block.visible = true;
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }
            console.log(counter);
```

Counter represented the number of visible blocks at any time which was significantly lower than the total number of blocks. However, my framerate plummeted by using this and trying to move around the scene was unbearable.

Comment: "occlusion culling" is when you want to avoid drawing elements of your scene that are inside the view frustum but are not visible from the camera. What you want to do is frustum culling.

Comment: Isn't frustrum culling where you don't draw objects that are not within the viewport. With frustrum culling, wouldn't it still draw objects that were way behind objects that are closer to the camera? I intend to hide the blocks that are in the ground, since I haven't "dug" down to see them yet. The frustrum will point down into the ground, collecting objects that the camera cannot actually see. I think that I do want occlusion culling, based on the way you described it.

Answer (score 0):

`Another idea I had was to merge all of the meshes together into one. That was great. I got incredible frame rates from this.`

This is the only solution if you want to draw a decent amount of cubes at 60 FPS. But instead of merging all the cubes into one gigantic mesh, merge group of cubes into a chunk and have multiple chunks to represent your world.

`Unfortunately I lost the ability to individually manipulate the specific blocks, and their unique textures were also lost. I'd need a way to be able to still reference, change materials for and remove blocks within that merged geometry. I don't think this is the solution.`

Assuming you have the chunk system setup, then instead of individual manipulation on the cubes, manipulate on the chunk level. Whenever a cube in a chunk is changed, generate a new chunk mesh data and upload that mesh into the GPU.

`Honestly I'm hoping someone here could explain how I can hide all of the meshes that are not visible because they are completely behind other objects.`

You cant. It is very very difficult (impossible in JS?) to do CPU based culling @60 FPS. Best you can do is a chunk-frustum test to see if the chunk is in viewport. Then leave the rest to the GPU and its depth test.

Comment: So I merge 4 blocks into one geometry to form a 2x2 block-group (chunk). I do that for all of the blocks. Then they left click on a "block" within a "chunk". I want to delete that "block" from within that "chunk". I somehow need to make a new "chunk" that is missing that "block", then replace it in the scene. How would I associated the clicked part of the merged geometry with the concept of a block?

Comment: You mean how to determine which cube you clicked on in a chunk?

Comment: That's what I mean. The two problems that I experienced when I tried to merge all objects into one is that I don't know how to determine which cube was clicked on in the merged geometry. The other problem I experienced is that I had to use one material to create the merged mesh, but I wanted each individual cube to have it's own material assigned. Once I've determined which cube was clicked on within a chunk, I need to actually be able to remove it.

Comment: Using your 2x2 chunk example. Suppose if you clicked at 3,3. First find the correct chunk to use through whatever means you use to organize the chunks. Then take that modulo of your clicked coordinate by chunk dimension. So in this case, 3%2; and thus you want the cube at local chunk coordinates(1,1). If you use a 2 dimensional array to store the cubes in chunk, the just access chunk.cubes[1][1].

Comment: For the material thing, I dont know enough about three.js (now that the webgl tag is removed) to implement it. But it is very possible. Perhaps ask another question specific to that and you will probably have some good answers.